# Laravel old for selectbox options

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, html-select

So i'm working on a standalone laravel project (still a bit new to this..). Using the same form blade file adding and editing records. I've set old to the fields for validation checks, however i can't seem to get old working correctly for dropdowns. The select options are loaded in a foreach, and ive got a check to set it to selected if the record on edit matches the dropdown option selected, however when i add the old method to it, select a new option (E.G. "broker") and force validation to throw an error it works as expected & saves whatever i've selected (option "broker"), it saves the option on submit, but then when i go to edit another record (option "assessor") it displays the same option i previously selected (option "broker")...if any of that made sense!

Here's the foreach with option select from the blade file:

```
<select class="form-control" name="other_party_details[party_type_id]" id="other_party_details[party_type_id]">
<option value="">--- Please Select ---</option>
@foreach($partyTypes as $partyType)
<option value="{{ $partyType->id }}" {{old('other_party_details.party_type_id', !empty($claim->otherParty->party_type_id)) == $partyType->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>
{{ $partyType->label }}
</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

What am i doing wrong?

I've exhausted google as for the most it seems to show results for multi select (mine is not), or using LaravelCollective (which i'm not), so running out of places to look!

Thanks in advance

Comment: what's name of select tag?

Comment: i've added the whole select code to the original question. Other fields (regular inputs) are also named as such in the html array format and old works as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code

```
<option value="{{$partyType->id}}" @if(old('party_type_id') == $partyType->id || $claim->otherParty->party_type_id == $partyType->id ) selected @endif> {{ $partyType->label }}</option>
```

Comment: Just replaced my option code with that and selected a different option on edit, but validation errors goes back to the original again instead of what was selected.

Comment: Is your select tag name  dynamic? i mean party_type_id in other_party_details[party_type_id] is dynamic?

Comment: You can change position of both conditions in if. Check edited answer

Comment: The select box isnt dynamic, it jut grabs all selections from the model and passes through to the blade file before being spat out in the foreach. swapping the conditions didnt change i'm afraid

Comment: It seems like there is no issue with your select tag code. Check your save method and make sure on saving correct rows and columns are updated.

Comment: Thanks, So it appears to be working. But if i edit the record, submit it, and then edit the record again, it doesnt seem to be updating the old method with what i've just selected, leading me to believe it's a session issue?